Is there any good necessary and sufficient condition for $L^{+\infty}(X,\mu)$ to be not separable?
Suppose that $(X,M,\mu)$ is an abstract measure space. Let $L^{+\infty}(X,\mu)$ to be the space of all essentially bounded measurable functions on $X$. Generally, $L^{+\infty}(X,\mu)$ is not separable, like $l^{+\infty} \ \text{and} \  L^{+\infty}$. Several good sufficient conditions for $L^{+\infty}(X,\mu)$ to be given, but I wonder if a necessary and sufficient condition exists.
Remark: I know a sufficient but not necessary condition:
Let $(X , M , \mu)$ be a measure space, then $L^{\infty}(X , \mu)$ is not separable if there exists a partition on $X$, $X = \cup_{k = 1}^{+\infty} X_k, \quad \text{with} \quad \mu(X_k) > 0, k = 1 , 2 , 3 , \ldots$.

The condition you wrote down in your remark is actually also necessary. Indeed, I claim that as long as $X$ is not a disjoint union of finitely many atoms, then such a partition exists. This can be constructed by induction - at step $k$, we will choose $X_k$ s.t. $\mu(X_k) > 0$, $X_k$ is disjoint from $X_1, \cdots, X_{k-1}$ that are already chosen, and $X \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^k X_i$ is not a disjoint union of finitely many atoms. This ends up giving a sequence of disjoint sets $X_k$ with $\mu(X_k) > 0$ for all $k$. To get a partition of $X$ itself, simply change $X_1$ to $X_1 \cup (X \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty X_i)$.
Thus, if no such partition exists, then $X = \bigcup_{i=1}^N A_i$ is a disjoint union of finitely many atoms $A_i$. But then $L^\infty(X, \mu) = \mathbb{C}^N$ is separable.
